# Problems populating the DataGridView DataSource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a form including the `DataGridView` `PeopleDataGridView`; it takes the table 'People' as `DataSource`.

The following code:

```
    Try

        Me.PeopleTableAdapter.FillByCode(Me.FamilyTreeDataBaseDataSet1.People, FirstName, LastName)

    Catch ex As System.Exception

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

   End Try
```

always outputs the error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I tried many things and nothing worked :/
Can you please help?
Lots of thanks ;)

Comment: _And it worked for a while and everything was fine, then it started to give me the following Error_: did you make any change in the data structure, SW version. Something should have been changed.

Comment: I was editing the sql I had in the code, though it was there originally and I just made adjustments to it.

Comment: Your whole question is unclear. Even your code doesn't help much: where is the DataGridView? And the DataSource? What is FillByCode?

Comment: The DataGridView is in a Form on its own. The DataSource is a MS Access file that I attached to the project.
FillByCode is the code that resulted from using query builder to show the criteria I want. It originally was in a ToolStrip but i copird the code and pasted it to form_Load event because that is where I need it.

Comment: If you only read the whole thing before editing the question -_-

Comment: maybe if u show the code that should fill the datagridview that would help us to identifie where this code might be wrong.  Without seeing the code there is no way on earth anybody can help u

Comment: That up there _is_ the code that should fill the dataGridView

Comment: It gives me the Same error for any DataGridView I use .. even if I don't change the code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So .. I found out what the problem was.

I changed a field in my MS Access Database from the name 'Notes' to 'NotesArabic'
The DataAdapter wouldn't even *preview* the table 'People' till I had it back to its original name.

Anyways .. Thanks for trying to help :)

Peace :D